# calling Webservices from jsp

Tags: java, web-services

I have created the wsdl successfully .Its url is "http://:/aebis/HelpdeskWebserviceImpl?wsdl".
Now I want to use this url to call the function in jsp.I am using Jboss as server.
Please suggest if any one can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason, you need it done within a JSP? If you have the chance to use recent technology, don't use JSPs any more. What you need is a client for your web service, for example generated by the wsimport tool from JDK, which then can be used for example by a JSF page.

Comment: how to use wsimport tool in web aaplication.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/WebServiceClient/WebServiceClient.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a 5-minute example using eclipse

I am gonna use this WSDL to demonstrate

http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAcceleration.asmx?WSDL

Create a dynamic java project for your JSPs

[image]

[image]

[image]

Create your JSP and some backend java class

[image]

your JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<%= new myweb.MyClass().getResult()  %>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
package myweb;

public class MyClass {

    public String getResult(){
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(c.getResult());

    }

}
```

Now create the WS client. Click on/select the project

[image]

right click and create a new Web Service Client from the given WSDL

[image]

[image]

Change MyClass to call the web service (you can test first using the class main too)

```
 package myweb;

 import java.rmi.RemoteException;

 import NET.webserviceX.www.AccelerationUnitSoap;
 import NET.webserviceX.www.AccelerationUnitSoapProxy;
 import NET.webserviceX.www.Accelerations;

 public class MyClass {

 public String getResult() throws RemoteException {
      AccelerationUnitSoap a = new AccelerationUnitSoapProxy();
      Accelerations x = Accelerations.decimeterPersquaresecond;
      Accelerations y = Accelerations.centimeterPersquaresecond;
      Object z = a.changeAccelerationUnit(1, x, y);
      return z.toString();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

      MyClass c = new MyClass();
      System.out.println(c.getResult());

 }

 }
```

Add the web app to your server (if there's one. If there isn't, create a new server)

[image]

Clear the server (forcing it to refresh the app) and start it

And here it is.

[image]

Comment: Great guide help me a lot. I wonder why it has so few upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The [wsimport tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) is part of the JDK and generates "portable artifacts" from a wsdl. That gives you classes to use easily for communicating with the web service without the need of doing the boilerplate code yourself.

But I feel that you may need some more background beforehand, to get a better understanding how to use JAX-RS web services or implement a state-of-the-art web application with JSF, so my advice is to consult the [Java EE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm) for those two (chapter 28 and 7).

Comment: Thanks for nice  answer with demo